# Configuring Java version for ANT in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

In IntelliJ if I want to configure the version of Java my ANT script uses I can just right click and set the properites for ANT and select the JDK I want to use.
In Eclipse I don't see any such option.  Do I need to hard code the version of Java into my Script or is there any way to tell ANT what version I want it to use?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this in the `Run Configuration`. Right click your ant file ant select `Run as` -> `Ant Build...`. On the `JRE` tab you can switch to any JRE.

Maybe you have to add the concerning JRE to eclipse first by clicking `Installed JREs...` this opens the Eclipse preferences dialog where you can add it.

Comment: Cheers,  that was it,  simple.  I've been scanning my workspace to see what file mentions the JDK that ANT is using ( As it shows in it's logging ) but couldn't find it.  Tried the system JAVA_HOME but that wasn't it. Thnx